# How to skip @Transient fields in querydsl generation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl, jpa

I have an `@Entity` class that I use `querydsl` code generation on.

Problem: my entity has a parent entity which contains some `@Transient` fields. And those are not skipped during generation.

```
package com.domain.myentity

@Entity
public class MyEntity extends AuditingEntity {

}


package com.auditing

@MappedSuperclass
public class AuditingEntity {
    @Transient
    private transient Object obj;
}
```

package-info.java:

```
@QueryEntities(value = MyEntity.class)
package com.domain.myentity

import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities;
import com.domain.myentity.MyEntity;
```

Question: how can I tell querydsl to ignore any `@Transient` fields automatically?
Currently the root cause is probably that the `AuditingEntity` is in a different folder than the domain entity, and therefore not listed in the `package-info.java` of querydsl. But how could I solve it without having to move the auditing entity?

Generated during:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please mark it as a correct answer - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent QueryDsl from mapping a field or method you should use
the ***@QueryType*** - annotation with ***PropertyType***.***NONE***.

> The value PropertyType.NONE can be used to skip a property in the query type generation. This case is different from @Transient or @QueryTransient annotated properties, where properties are not persisted. PropertyType.NONE just omits the property from the Querydsl query type.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {


    @QueryType(PropertyType.NONE)
    public String stringNotInQuerydsl;

}
```

See the official documentation [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch03s03.html)

Answer (score 3):

Could you try transient declaration as `transient String obj;`
instead of

```
@Transient
private Object obj;
```

Comment: Tried it, but problem remains.